# a strange C++ segment fault

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

Why this code appear segment fault？

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int *role;
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",role);

    return 0;
}
```

...but the second one is ok:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int *role = new int;
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",role);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because in first case `role` doesn't point to anything. In other words, it is uninitialized and you're using it. So the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: You never put a value in "role", it contains a garbage address. Then you tell sscanf to write the decoded `int` to the garbage address. You mean `int role; sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &role);`

Answer (score 2):

In the first one, `role` is an uninitialized pointer: it's not pointing to any memory that you "own". So the `sscanf` function is writing the result into that area of memory, and (rightly) failing.

Comment: In the first exapmple, role is not assigned with any value (only DECLARED), so no space is allocated in your memory. Maybe try using malloc() (https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) to pre-allocate memory or you just use the second example.